# Particle effect with libgdx - box2d

Tags: libgdx, box2d, collision, particle-system, particles

I'm developing a game which basically involves a lot of collisions and explosions. Now, whenever I have a collision between two bodies, I want to draw a particle effect like an explosion at the collision position, but I'm not sure how do I do that. Normally I know how to draw particles but because I'm using box2d and I'm not using pixels but meters(every pixel is 32 meters), I'm not sure what size should the particle effect be.

If you guys could help me out here I would really appreaciate that.

Comment: Every meter is 32 pixels right? Well just play arround with it. Create a particle effekt (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Particle-Editor) and draw it (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2d-particle-effects). The play arround with the size and other params.

Comment: Particles are sized in WORLD coordinates. So size them in the editor the same size (or there and there abouts) as your box2d/sprites  : since you're using box 2d you'll already be using a suitable "world coordinate" viewport one would hope.